# Use foreach loop with array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array represent by `$details_sort`.

I want to use my array  in foreach loop.

```
like foreach (`$details_sort` as $detail)
{


} 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [score] => 233
            [user_id] => 4
            [date] => 2014-02-03 00:00:00

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [score] => 1256
            [user_id] => 5
            [date] => 2014-02-05 00:00:00

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [score] => 123
            [user_id] => 7
            [date] => 2014-03-04 00:00:00

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [score] => 100

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [score] => 8
            [user_id] => 2
            [date] => 2014-03-13 00:00:00

        )

)
```

Comment: http://de3.php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: "I want to my array in foreach loop." I don't even know what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($details_sort as $detail) {
    foreach($detail as $attribute => $value) {
        echo "$attribute => $value";
    }
}
```

or

```
foreach($details_sort as $detail) {
    echo $detail['id'];
    echo $detail['score'];
    echo $detail['userid'];
    echo $detail['date'];
}
```

Comment: where did i miss quotes? Please specify :)

Comment: `echo $detail['userid];` should be `echo $detail['userid'];`

Comment: Ah, you have debugging eyes, well spotted @AwladLiton

Answer (score 0):

This really basic of php. you should have some efforts.
[see php foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
 foreach ($details_sort as $detail)
    {
    echo $detail['id'];
    echo $detail['score'];
    echo $detail['user_id'];
    echo $detail['date'];

    }
```